# Content-Range header IThitWebDav server

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server, http-content-range

I have installed ITHIT webdav server engine. I tried using CalDev and Class1 server engine instances.

However, I was not successful with enabling content-range header.

When I am sending PUT with content-range header includes, the IIS server is responding with 501 not implemented.

Kindly help in resolving content-range header issue.

Answer (score 0):

Typically CalDAV clients do not send PUT with Content-Range. The sample CalDAV implementation, generated by [CalDAV/CardDAV Web Application wizard](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/vs_wizards) for Visual Studio does not implement resumable upload.

If you really need resumable upload in CalDAV/CardDAV server, you can modify the [IContent](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.IContent.html).[Write](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.IContent.Write.html) method implementation. This method provides necessary parameters to process segmented uploads. By default you can find the Write method in CalendarFile.cs file.